# Pythonic string.replace() in Nim?

Tags: nim-lang

How to replace some string with Nim ?

```
var pythonista:string = "Power of Python!"
echo pythonista
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

First, you need to import `strutils` module. [Strutils](https://nim-lang.org/docs/strutils.html#replace%2Cstring%2Cstring%2Cstring) is the module that defines several common functions for working with strings.

So the code will be like this:

```nim
import std/strutils
    
var pythonista:string = "Power of Python!"
echo pythonista
echo "============"
echo pythonista.replace("Python!", "Nim :)")
echo "============"
```

Comment: One thing I'd want to clarify to prevent confusion is that strutils is not a "system" module. You can call it a standard library module, but not system, as https://nim-lang.org/docs/system.html is the "main" module that's always implicitly imported in all Nim files, and it's not related to strutils.

Another small note - it's recommended to import stdlib modules with the `std` namespace prefix, so

`import std/strutils`

Comment: @Yardanico, oh, I see. That was inattentive on my part. I'll fix my answer.